# Decrease document reads in Firestore, react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat app in react using Firebase Firestore as backend database.

I get recent 25 messages in useEffect hook as

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
        collection(db, 'messages'),
        orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'),
        limit(25)
    );

    return onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        setData(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                console.log('document read');
                return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
            })
        );
    });
}, []);
```

But this operation results in 25 document reads on page load and 50 additional on sending a message.
If more users are connected, 25 request per user happen on single message send by any user.
Is there any way to reduce the reads?

Complete code:- https://github.com/Puneet56/Converse

Answer (score 2):

You don't get 25 reads in a running query with a limit of 25 resulst if you get a new one inside. As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) says:

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
> also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
> because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
> deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

As stated in the docs you will be charged only for the one that is `added` and the one that get's out of the query limit because a new one got in. So you get probably only 2 reads per new message. I think that is a reasonable amount. I can't any way to reduce this amount in a chat App. Even if you would increase the query limit only your inital `reads` (if it's a fresh read with no old or empty cache) will increas to but the reads while listening would stay the same.

Comment: I reloaded the app 4 times(100 reads) and same is increased in Usage tab. Then I sent 4 messages and usage increased by 100 again. It is charging for each doc read. Message not stored locally as they have to be updated in real-time.

Comment: Reloading the page means all memory is cleared and the database has to load the 25 documents again. But sending a message while the page remains open will add only a single document read charge. If you also want to reduce document read charges between page loads, [enabled offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) for the client.

Comment: Maybe I should stored some certain message locally on app load and set listener with limit(1).

Comment: Even if you would do that and only one document changes you still would get one read for adding the new and one for removing the old one from that limit(1). To be clear again: You can't do anything better than it is. You can enable the offline as stated by @FrankvanPuffelen to improve the offline behaviour and save reads in some situations. But the amount of reads while having a realtime listener in a chat won't change.

Comment: @TarikHuber A document that falls out of a query does not cause a document read charge. So if a new document is added while you have an active listener it will case a single document read charge.

Comment: OK. Then I did not understand this part from the docs corectly: "You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed" Is this only when a document get's removed while it changes so it doesn't fit in a query result?